# Abp boilerplate Localization by QueryStringRequestCultureProvider for custom language

Tags: localization, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I try to use localization method `L()` in *MyController* for getting localization string from my *custom added language*(not standart for boilerplate - swedish).

Regarding to documentation (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization)
I can add **queryStringParameter** to request `culture=sv` (my source localization file is `Abp-sv.xml`)
I added this parameter but `L("SomeString)` returns localization for default language.

**If I use culture for standart ASP.NET Boilerplate languages ar, de, etc. then it works.**

Comment: Did you add language to application?

Comment: Thank you so much @aaron 
I didn't know it. My DB doesn't include swedish language. I just added it, and currently it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @aaron
It didn't work because my DB doesn't include row with my custom language. **queryStringParameter** works just in case if you add your language to application.
You can do it just by this code

```
Configuration.Localization.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("en", "English", "famfamfam-flags gb", true));
```

Or as in my case, by adding it to DB, and abp'll add it in your application.